# Numerically solving a non-linear and with infinite domain integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have tried NDsolve but failed. Would there be any way to solve this equation numerically using Mathematica?

Here is the code:

```
con = y[1] == 0;
NDSolve[{9 x \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(x\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\((\(-\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\*FractionBox[\(y[s]\), SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]] \[DifferentialD]s\)\) + y[t])\) \[DifferentialD]t\)\) == 14 + 5/(-1 + Derivative[1][y][x]), con}, {y[x]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Please add the code for the equation and the `NDSolve` you've tried. Is there an error message?

Comment: @keerZhang The first double integral evaluates to  `-9x (Infinity-x)Integrate[y[s]/s^2,{s,1,Infinity}]`. Is this correct&intended?